# I¨m struggling with DATA_ADD

Tags: mysql

I want to use DATAADD on my table which i have called "trainig_session", but get a error message which i dont understand why.

```
SELECT start_time, DATAADD(start_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS 
end_time FROM training_session where activity = "Running"

I get a error message which i dont understand why
```

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBNUw.png)
[My Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcsdf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql You should use  DATE_ADD()

```
SELECT start_time, DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_time 
FROM training_session
 where activity = "Running"
```

or ADDDATE()

```
SELECT start_time, ADDDATE(start_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_time 
FROM training_session
 where activity = "Running"
```